# Real-life application of sinc-in-time data or sinc(t) function?

Tags: functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics, continuous-fourier

I found that my customers' response time on an application is varying in a Sinc-in-time fashion. i.e. Sinc(t) across time. Can this information be applied to obtain any relevant system other than just for a fun observation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you customers' response is following a diminishing oscillatory response as plotted below, you could apply measurements to create a PID controller.

```
Plot[{2, -2 Sinc[x] + 2}, {x, 0, 6 Pi},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 3}},
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Automatic},
 Epilog -> {
   Inset[Style["Initiation", 14], {3, 0.2}],
   Inset[Style["Response", 14], {14, 2.2}]}]
```

[image]

With variation in the terms you can modify the response to follow a path such as shown below.

Ref: [PID controller theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#PID_controller_theory)

[image]

There is also a relevant Mathematica demonstration: [PID Control of a Tank Level](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PIDControlOfATankLevel/)